# Почему при функциональном выражении не работает тернарный оператор?

Tags: javascript

Если я пишу функциональное выражение с помощью конструкции if else

```
const plantNeedsWater = function (day) {
    if (day === 'Wednesday') {
      return (true)
    } else {
      return(false)
    }
}
console.log(plantNeedsWater('Tuesday'))
// return false
```

То всё идёт хорошо, а если я использую тернарный оператор

```
const plantNeedsWater = function (day) {
    day === 'Wednesday' ? console.log(true) : console.log(false)
}
console.log(plantNeedsWater('Tuesday'))
```

То выводится ошибка в чём дело?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в некорректном преобразовании к тернарному оператору.

Стоит обратить внимание, что начальная функция возвращает значение, версия же с тернарным оператором сама выводит лог.

Таким образом нужно либо изменить функцию

```
const plantNeedsWater = function (day) {
    return day === 'Wednesday' ? (true) : (false)
}
```

Либо изменить вызов этой функции

```
plantNeedsWater('Tuesday');
```

Comment: Заметка: Стоит заметить, что если нужно вернуть true/false, то достаточно написать `return day === 'Wednesday'`.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, в некоторых командах специально линтеры стоят на полное сравнение

Comment: ........Глупцы))

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, кто-то считает, что `a== false` понятнее чем `!a` ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: ага)) смешно смотреть на выражения типа: `userIsAdmin ? true : false` :D  или `userIsAdmin === true ? true : false` xDDD

Answer (score 0):

Потому что в функции с тернарником нет `return` и зачем-то используются ненужные консоль логи

Comment: зато там есть свои console.log :)

Comment: Тобишь в тернарнике нельзя использовать консоль логи и ретюрны, правильно понял?

Comment: @ИванИпатов, неправильно.

Comment: Прошу прощения нельзя использовать только ретюрны, а консоль лог можно?

Comment: @ИванИпатов можно всё. только выражение в тернарнике неравнозначно тому, что без тернарника.... куда должен возращаться результат тернарника? и почему внезапно в тернарнике консоль логи появились? Зачем?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский у меня на курсе сейчас функциональные выражения и там они написаны только с помощью if else и я решил попробовать с тернарным способом.

Comment: @ИванИпатов всё понятно. просто логично же, что функции должны содержать одну и ту же логику, правда? а у вас она явно различается. поэтому и проблема с "неработающим" тернарником

Comment: @АлексейШиманский да, спасибо, понял-различил